# Override Mage_Checkout_Block_Onepage with an extension

Tags: onepage-checkout, overrides, extensions

I'm aiming to override the class Mage_Checkout_Block_Onepage in order to begin a rework of the onepage checkout. Unfortunately, i fail to success at overriding it, while the onePageController override works fine. My package name is Ohwee, my extension name is ThirdStepsCheckout.

Files in my extension:

```
Checkout/
    Block/
        Onepage.php
controllers/
    OnepageController.php
etc/
    config.xml
```

Here's my config.xml file :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Ohwee_ThirdStepsCheckout>
            <version>0.1.0</version>
        </Ohwee_ThirdStepsCheckout>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <blocks>
            <checkout>
                <rewrite>
                    <onepage>
                        Ohwee_ThirdStepsCheckout_Block_Onepage
                    </onepage>
                </rewrite>
            </checkout>
        </blocks>
    </global>
    <frontend>
        <routers>
            <checkout>
                <args>
                    <modules>
                        <ohwee_thirdstepscheckout before="Mage_Checkout">Ohwee_ThirdStepsCheckout</ohwee_thirdstepscheckout>
                    </modules>
                </args>
            </checkout>
        </routers>
    </frontend>
</config>
```

at the time, the block class Onepage.php is just a test to see if the override is working :

```
<?php 
require_once 'Mage/Checkout/Block/Onepage.php';

class Ohwee_ThirdStepsCheckout_Block_Onepage extends Mage_Checkout_Block_Onepage {
    public function getSteps()
    {
        exit('custom steps');
    }
}
?>
```

The problem is I don't see the exit on front, but the layout is now empty, so it seems the original Mage controller isn't called either. If i delete the config.xml part about overriding the block, checkout is functional again. I can't see from where the issue come from,any ideas ?

I'm on Magento CE 1.8.0.1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved by naming the class `Ohwee_ThirdStepsCheckout_Checkout_Block_Onepage` instead of `Ohwee_ThirdStepsCheckout_Block_Onepage`

Answer (score 2):

Change this:

```
                <onepage>
                    Ohwee_ThirdStepsCheckout_Block_Onepage
                </onepage>
```

Into this:

```
<onepage>Ohwee_ThirdStepsCheckout_Block_Onepage</onepage>
```

Magento does not trim the spaces.
And you don't need

```
require_once 'Mage/Checkout/Block/Onepage.php';
```

the blocks, helpers and models are autoloaded. the require is only needed for controllers.

Comment: Thanks. I edited my config.xml as you suggested, i still got an empty layout in front, but this was for sure a part of the issue. removed the require_once too since it's useless.

Comment: there are basic issue with space at confog.xml

Comment: I tried a few more things on the config file, making new file and re-save it, suppress indent, putting all in one line, none of these solved the empty layout i got in front. Still, it looks a lot like an issue on config.xml