# Block rewrite not working - Mage_Checkout_Block_Onepage

Tags: checkout, onepage-checkout, overrides

I am having an issue with rewriting the Mage_Checkout_Block_Onepage block.

The issue is that after enabling this rewrite in the config, the one page checkout page doesn't load with any content. I have found that the Mage_Checkout_Block_Onepage block is never loaded.

I have the following in my config.xml

```
<blocks>
 <checkout>
  <rewrite>
   <onepage>Name_Module_Checkout_Block_Onepage</onepage>
  </rewrite>
 </checkout>
</blocks>
```

I then have the following class created in

```
app\code\local\Name\Module\Block\Checkout\Onepage.php

class Name_Module_Checkout_Block_Onepage extends Mage_Checkout_Block_Onepage {
```

I then override the getSteps method to see if its getting called, but it never gets called.

```
public function getSteps()
{
        Mage::Log("HERE!~");
}
```

I also created a new template file in the following location. Which is just a copy of the original onepage.phtml for now.

```
app\design\frontend\base\default\template\[module]\checkout\onepage.phtml
```

What is odd is that I can put a random name in the config.xml for the rewrite class and it never throws an error saying it can't find the class.

The same issue as described here [Override Mage_Checkout_Block_Onepage with an extension](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/43760/override-mage-checkout-block-onepage-with-an-extension)

I looked through this question, but it didn't really have a solution. I tried everything that it said.

Any ideas would be very helpful. I must be missing something somewhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your path is not correct

```
app\code\local\Name\Module\Block\Checkout\Onepage.php

class Name_Module_Checkout_Block_Onepage extends Mage_Checkout_Block_Onepage {
```

Should be (same as the class name)

```
  <rewrite>
   <onepage>Name_Module_Block_Checkout_Onepage</onepage>
  </rewrite>

app\code\local\Name\Module\Block\Checkout\Onepage.php

class Name_Module_Block_Checkout_Onepage extends Mage_Checkout_Block_Onepage {
```

Comment: Oh wow, I feel stupid now. It works now! Thanks!